# How to block a referral site in htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress

I started my blog a few days ago, and after publishing a few articles, I wanted to create backlinks. Doing that, I found a site called blogarama.com. I didn't check reviews first and added my site to it. That site adds my articles directly to it and gives backlinks to them. After a few days, I noticed increased traffic on my site from that site. But then I checked reviews of that site, and they said it sends bot traffic and harms sites. I tried to remove my site from that site, but there was no option. I even try to mail them, but that's also not working. Then I find that I can block sites in my htaccess, but I don't know how to. Please help.

I try to block that site in google analytics, but that's not working.

Adding this will work?

> RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} blogarama.com [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} [www.blogarama.com](http://www.blogarama.com) RewriteRule .* - [F]

Answer (score 0):

Change the domain in the first line of the rule to target the domain you wish to block.

```
   SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "siteNameTobeBlack.com" bad_referer
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from ALL
    Deny from env=bad_referer
```

Ensure mod_setenvif directives enabled